# Prove that a point x not belonging to a closed set M \subset (x,d) always has a nonzero distance from M

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I am sure this proof is pretty straight forward and I know that I somehow will need to show that $x$ is in $A^\prime$ if and only if $D(x,A) = 0$, where $A$ is any nonempty subset of $X$.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: The statement that you "know that you somehow need to show" rephrases the thing you're trying to prove — actually it's stronger (iff not just if-then). However, assuming $A'$ is the limit points of $A$, what you have isn't quite right, you want to say this about the closure of A: $x \in cl(A) \iff D(x,A)=0$.  // What have you tried?

Comment: I apologize, I am very lost with this and I am having the most trouble trying to figure out where to start. Since x does not belong to M, I am not sure what approach to take. If someone could give me some clarification on the starting point, I think I should be able to understand it from there. Thank you.

Comment: AreaMan's answer should be a good start — can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show: if $A$ is closed, then if $d(x,A) = 0$, then $x \in A$?

Hint: We would like to use the hypothesis that $A$ is closed. Think of the counter example, $(0,1)$ and the point $1$. So we must build a sequence of points in $A$ which converge to $x$. This can be done by considering the sequence of balls $B_{1/n}(x)$, for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$.